# bash script commands seperated by space

Tags: bash, shell-script

Saying that I have a bash script `/home/me/test/sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cmd                              # here is the output of the cmd
pwd echo 'aaa'                     # /home/me
val=pwd echo 'aaa'                 # aaa
val=pwd echo 'aaa'$val             # aaa

val=pwd echo 'aaa' && echo $val    # aaa <and an empty line>
```

I can't quite understand how these bash codes seperated by a space works.

BTW, I pose this question because I just installed ROS and a bash script named `setup.sh` was generated, and I'm reading this script. There is a line as below:

```
CATKIN_SHELL=bash /opt/ros/kinetic/_setup_util.py >> file.log
```

Comment: Commands cannot be separated by just spaces in the shell. The only one of your examples that contains more than one command is the last, where the two commands are separated by `&&`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson There is only one single command in the code, the first `pwd` (with too many arguments). The rest is a syntax error due to the unterminated command substitution (unbalanced backticks).  (Now edited by Filipe Brandenburger).

Comment: I too cannot understand your bash code ...

Comment: @RoVo  Install ROS and read its `setup.sh`, you will get what I posed here... Seriously I got no idea why it wrote such a code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I think what is tripping you here is the command format where the first word(s) in the command are a variable assignment (which the shell determines based on the presence of a `=`.)

In those cases, the shell will evaluate those assignments, but it will *only* export those variables in the command that it is running. In particular, the shell itself won't have access to those variables.

This is useful for running commands or scripts that are affected by environment variables, in which case you don't need to export them in a shell and can just set them as "one-offs" for that single execution.

Let's break down your commands and explain them one by one:

```
pwd echo 'aaa'                     # /home/me
```

Ok, so this is running the `pwd` command and passing it two arguments, `echo` and `aaa`. But `pwd` doesn't take arguments, so it's just ignoring those two and printing the local directory.

```
val=pwd echo 'aaa'                 # aaa
```

So as I explained, this performs the variable assignment, setting `$val` to contain the string `pwd` and then executes the `echo` command with the `aaa` argument. The `$val` variable is available **only** to the `echo` command and not to the shell itself! The `echo` command doesn't really do anything with that variable, so it simply goes ahead and prints `aaa`. After this command is finished, the `$val` variable is **not** defined in the shell.

```
val=pwd echo 'aaa'$val             # aaa
```

So, again, similar to the command above. This one gets tricky, since you might expect the final `$val` to get expanded. But variables are expanded *by the shell*, not by the commands. And, as explained, the shell doesn't really see `$val` which is set to `pwd`, only the command (in this case, `echo`) does, so `$val` gets expanded to an empty string, and this is exactly equivalent to the above.

```
val=pwd echo 'aaa' && echo $val    # aaa <and an empty line>
```

And one more time, `$val` is not available after the first `echo` command completes, so the second `echo $val` will print nothing (just the blank line), as `$val` was never really set in the shell itself throughout this execution.

If you want to set `$val` in the shell, then you need to make that assignment a standalone, without any commands. For instance, this behaves differently from the above:

```
$ val=pwd; echo 'aaa' && echo $val
aaa
pwd
```

Since `val=pwd` is followed by a `;`, then the shell considers it a command on its own and will set `$val` in the current shell, so the `echo $val` will work as you expect.

(Note that there's one more difference here, since with `val=pwd; ...`, the variable `$val` is not really exported, so `echo` will **not** see that variable in its environment, while with `val=pwd echo ...` it *would* get exported, but then in that case, it is not available in the shell.)

And considering you're using `pwd`, I wonder if what you wanted was to store the output of that command in the variable... In which case, you need to use [shell command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), either using backticks, or better yet, surrounding the command with `$(` and `)`.

So one final example here:

```
$ val=$(pwd); echo 'aaa' && echo $val
aaa
/home/me
```

Or:

```
$ val=$(pwd) && echo 'aaa' && echo $val
aaa
/home/me
```

(There's a subtle difference here, where the latter will break execution if the command inside the substitution, in this case `pwd`, fails and exits with a non-zero status, in which case the following commands will not be executed. When using `;` that's not the case, the following commands are executed even if the first one fails.)

I hope this explains what you weren't understanding about these commands!

Answer (score 0):

the code below may help to understand how this construct works:

```
$ cd tmprun/
$ cat run.sh 
echo $a
$ ./run.sh 

$ a=bla ./run.sh 
bla
```

Comment: It probably does, but I still have the feeling that a few words of explanation might help those who are very unfamiliar with the concept (such as, e.g., the OP) ...